# How can I pass git SHA1 to compiler as definition using cmake?

Tags: git, cmake, sha1

In a Makefile this would be done with something like:

```
g++ -DGIT_SHA1="`git log -1 | head -n 1`" ...
```

This is very useful, because the binary knows exact commit SHA1 so it can dump it in case of segfault.

How can I achieve the same with CMake?

Comment: Use `git describe` (producing output such as 'v1.6.5-rc1-17-g059f3d9') or `git rev-parse -q HEAD` (producing full SHA-1) instead of your `git log -1 | head -n 1` pipeline.

Comment: git describe --tags works great

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I've made some CMake modules that peer into a git repo for versioning and similar purposes - they're all in my repository at https://github.com/rpavlik/cmake-modules

The good thing about these functions is, they will force a re-configure (a rerun of cmake) before a build every time the HEAD commit changes. Unlike doing something just once with execute_process, you don't need to remember to re-cmake to update the hash definition.

For this specific purpose, you'd need at least the `GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake` and `GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake.in` files. Then, in your main `CMakeLists.txt` file, you'd have something like this

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/whereYouPutMyModules/")
include(GetGitRevisionDescription)
get_git_head_revision(GIT_REFSPEC GIT_SHA1)
```

Then, you could either add it as a system-wide definition (which unfortunately would cause lots of rebuilding)

```
add_definitions("-DGIT_SHA1=${GIT_SHA1}")
```

or, my suggested alternative: Make a generated source file.  Create these two files in your source:

*GitSHA1.cpp.in:*

```
#define GIT_SHA1 "@GIT_SHA1@"
const char g_GIT_SHA1[] = GIT_SHA1;
```

*GitSHA1.h:*

```
extern const char g_GIT_SHA1[];
```

Add this to your `CMakeLists.txt` (assuming you have a list of source files in SOURCES):

```
configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/GitSHA1.cpp.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitSHA1.cpp" @ONLY)
list(APPEND SOURCES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GitSHA1.cpp" GitSHA1.h)
```

Then, you have a global variable containing your SHA string - the header with the extern doesn't change when the SHA does, so you can just include that any place you want to refer to the string, and then only the generated CPP needs to be recompiled on every commit to give you access to the SHA everywhere.

Comment: Do you have a module to ensure out of source build?

Comment: Yes, there's one for out of source build - it's in the cmake-2.9.0-modules directory, and if you do include(UseBackportedModules) that automatically gets included.  I've contributed some patches back to cmake, but haven't felt the need to have new modules included - I'm fine with having them up on GitHub for easy sharing and collaboration unlinked from the CMake release cycle.

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work from within a submodule? It seems to return the parent project's SHA1 instead.

Comment: @JackPoulson, you might have a look at my fork of Ryan's repository which aims to fix the usage in submodules. https://github.com/PiQuer/cmake-modules

Comment: Thanks for that solution. In my C++ shared library I had to use the extern keyword in the cpp file as well. Otherwise it defaults to internal linkage because of the const, resulting in undefined references at link time.

Comment: Nice answer! But for me there was one thing missing. I needed to add `#include "GitSHA1.h"` in *GitSHA1.cpp.in* to properly export the global variable into a static library.

Comment: FWIW, I believe I have incorporated the patch mentioned by @PiQuer.

Comment: Could you explain the need for using `configure_file()` on `GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake.in`? Is this what forces the reconfigure?

Comment: I believe so, IIRC. I do think that I have one additional step there, that I'm forcing the reconfigure "too hard" - and that newer versions of CMake have a command to just explicitly make a given file change cause a reconfigure, but this script has been working well enough that I haven't looked into it. An updated version is maintained on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you @PiQuer for that comment. It saved my day! Could you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: It seems that rebuilding directly via Visual Studio does not update the source file.

Comment: IIRC, there's a "special project" CMake makes in the solution (something like ZERO_CHECK) that runs CMake, and while it is a dependency of all projects, you can manage to make VS build a project without it I think. But, the normal "Build Solution" should work fine.

Comment: A potential alternative to the global "add_definitions" would be to only add that definition to the source file / target within your project that is actually using it. set_property(SOURCE MyFile.cpp PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS GIT_SHA1="${GIT_SHA1}")

Comment: Yes, that's a great addition. When I originally wrote this answer, that capability did not exist.

Comment: Is there a way to also get the date of the hash?

Comment: I think you can do so by specifying a custom format to `git log`. The principle is the same though.

Answer (score 30):

I did this in such as way as to generate:

```cpp
const std::string Version::GIT_SHA1 = "e7fb69fb8ee93ac66f006406781138562d0250fb";
const std::string Version::GIT_DATE = "Thu Jan 9 14:17:56 2014";
const std::string Version::GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT = "Fix all the bugs";
```

If the workspace that performed the build had pending, uncommitted changes, the above SHA1 string will be suffixed with `-dirty`.

In `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# the commit's SHA1, and whether the building workspace was dirty or not
execute_process(COMMAND
  "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" describe --match=NeVeRmAtCh --always --abbrev=40 --dirty
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_SHA1
  ERROR_QUIET OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

# the date of the commit
execute_process(COMMAND
  "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" log -1 --format=%ad --date=local
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_DATE
  ERROR_QUIET OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

# the subject of the commit
execute_process(COMMAND
  "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" log -1 --format=%s
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT
  ERROR_QUIET OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

# generate version.cc
configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.cc.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cc" @ONLY)

list(APPEND SOURCES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cc" version.hh)
```

This requires `version.cc.in`:

```cpp
#include "version.hh"

using namespace my_app;

const std::string Version::GIT_SHA1 = "@GIT_SHA1@";
const std::string Version::GIT_DATE = "@GIT_DATE@";
const std::string Version::GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT = "@GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT@";
```

And `version.hh`:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace my_app
{
  struct Version
  {
    static const std::string GIT_SHA1;
    static const std::string GIT_DATE;
    static const std::string GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT;
  };
}
```

Then in code I can write:

```cpp
cout << "Build SHA1: " << Version::GIT_SHA1 << endl;
```

Comment: You still need to add a `find_package(Git)`.

Comment: I think you are missing a dependency check. After commit, version.cc should be generated again (new hash, and no dirty).

Answer (score 15):

It would be nice to have a solution that catches changes to the repository (from `git describe --dirty`), but only triggers recompilation if something about the git information has changed.

Some of the existing solutions:

1. Use `execute_process`. This only gets the git information at configure time, and can miss changes to the repository.
2. Depend on `.git/logs/HEAD`.  This only triggers recompilation when something in the repo changes, but misses the changes to get the `-dirty` state.
3. Use a custom command to rebuild the version information every time a build is run.  This catches changes resulting in the `-dirty` state, but triggers a recompilation all the time (based on the updated timestamp of the version information file)

One fix to the third solution is to use the CMake `copy_if_different` command, so the timestamp on the version information file only changes if the contents change.

The steps in the custom command are:

1. Collect the git information to a temporary file
2. Use `copy_if_different` to copy the temporary file to the real file
3. Delete the temporary file, to trigger the custom command to run again on the next `make`

The code (borrowing heavily from kralyk's solution):

```
# The 'real' git information file
SET(GITREV_BARE_FILE git-rev.h)
# The temporary git information file
SET(GITREV_BARE_TMP git-rev-tmp.h)
SET(GITREV_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${GITREV_BARE_FILE})
SET(GITREV_TMP ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${GITREV_BARE_TMP})

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
  OUTPUT ${GITREV_TMP}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo_append "#define GIT_BRANCH_RAW " > ${GITREV_TMP}
  COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD >> ${GITREV_TMP}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo_append "#define GIT_HASH_RAW " >> ${GITREV_TMP}
  COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} describe --always --dirty --abbrev=40 --match="NoTagWithThisName" >> ${GITREV_TMP}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${GITREV_TMP} ${GITREV_FILE}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove ${GITREV_TMP}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  VERBATIM
)
# Finally, the temporary file should be added as a dependency to the target

ADD_EXECUTABLE(test source.cpp ${GITREV_FILE})
```

(Edit: update GITREV_TMP to GITREV_FILE in ADD_EXECUTABLE)

Comment: I think it should be `${GITREV_FILE}` in `ADD_EXECUTABLE`. This solution is nice, however the only drawback is `${GITREV_FILE}` will not be deleted when `make clean`.

Comment: ... and also the OUTPUT should be ${GITREV_FILE}

Comment: Would explicitly adding the GENERATED property though set_source_files_properties help?

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/GENERATED.html

It also looks like output is now auto-considered generated so may not be necessary.

Comment: The correct semantics appear to be to have `${GITREV_FILE}` as `BYPRODUCT` but that only works with Ninja generator. Otherwise either still get perpetual rebuilds, or non-guaranteed rebuilds.

Answer (score 10):

I'd use something like this in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND git describe
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE VERSION )

string( REGEX MATCH "-g.*$" VERSION_SHA1 ${VERSION} )
string( REGEX REPLACE "[-g]" "" VERSION_SHA1 ${VERSION_SHA1} )

add_definitions( -DGIT_SHA1="${VERSION_SHA1}" )
```

Comment: Note that `exec_program` is [deprecated](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/exec_program.html). Instead, you can use the simpler `execute_process`, e.g. for this case: `execute_process(
    COMMAND git describe
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE VERSION )` (It looks busy as a single line, which is what I can produce in a comment, but is quite a bit cleaner when properly line-wrapped and indented.)

Answer (score 10):

### Solution

Simply adding some code to only 2 files: `CMakeList.txt` and `main.cpp`.

#### 1. CMakeList.txt

```
# git commit hash macro
execute_process(
  COMMAND git log -1 --format=%h
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_HASH
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
add_definitions("-DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=\"${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}\"")
```

#### 2. main.cpp

```
inline void LogGitCommitHash() {
#ifndef GIT_COMMIT_HASH
#define GIT_COMMIT_HASH "0000000" // 0000000 means uninitialized
#endif
    std::cout << "GIT_COMMIT_HASH[" << GIT_COMMIT_HASH << "]"; // 4f34ee8
}
```

### Explanation

In `CMakeList.txt`, the CMake command`execute_process()` is used to call command `git log -1 --format=%h` that give you the short and unique abbreviation for your SHA-1 values in string like `4f34ee8`. This string is assigned to CMake variable called `GIT_COMMIT_HASH`. The CMake command `add_definitions()` defines the macro `GIT_COMMIT_HASH` to the value of `4f34ee8` just before gcc compilation. The hash value is used to replace the macro in C++ code by preprocessor, and hence exists in the object file `main.o` and in the compiled binaries `a.out`.

### Side Note

Another way to achieve is to use CMake command called `configure_file()`, but I don't like to use it because the file does not exist before CMake is run.

Comment: This seems to force a complete rebuild everytime cmake is run.

Answer (score 7):

The following solution is based on the observation that Git updates the HEAD log whenever you `pull` or `commit` something. Note that e.g. Drew's suggestion above will update the Git information only if you rebuild the CMake cache manually after every `commit`.

I use a CMake "custom command" that generates a one-line header file `${SRCDIR}/gitrevision.hh` where `${SRCDIR}` is the root of your source tree. It will be re-made *only* when a new commit is made. Here is the necessary CMake magic with some comments:

```
# Generate gitrevision.hh if Git is available
# and the .git directory is present
# this is the case when the software is checked out from a Git repo
find_program(GIT_SCM git DOC "Git version control")
mark_as_advanced(GIT_SCM)
find_file(GITDIR NAMES .git PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
if (GIT_SCM AND GITDIR)
    # Create gitrevision.hh
    # that depends on the Git HEAD log
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${SRCDIR}/gitrevision.hh
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo_append "#define GITREVISION " > ${SRCDIR}/gitrevision.hh
        COMMAND ${GIT_SCM} log -1 "--pretty=format:%h %ai" >> ${SRCDIR}/gitrevision.hh
        DEPENDS ${GITDIR}/logs/HEAD
        VERBATIM
    )
else()
    # No version control
    # e.g. when the software is built from a source tarball
    # and gitrevision.hh is packaged with it but no Git is available
    message(STATUS "Will not remake ${SRCDIR}/gitrevision.hh")
endif()
```

The contents of `gitrevision.hh` will look like this:

```
#define GITREVISION cb93d53 2014-03-13 11:08:15 +0100
```

If you want to change this then edit the `--pretty=format:` specification accordingly. E.g. using `%H` instead of `%h` will print the full SHA1 digest. See the Git manual for details.

Making `gitrevision.hh` a fully-fledged C++ header file with include guards etc. is left as an exercise to the reader :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution, which I think is reasonably short yet effective ;-)

First, a file is needed in the source tree (I name it `git-rev.h.in`), it should looks something like this:

```
#define STR_EXPAND(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_EXPAND(x)
#define GIT_REV STR(GIT_REV_)
#define GIT_REV_ \
```

(Please never mind those macros, that's a little bit insane trick to make a string out of a raw value.)
It is essential that this file has **exactly** one empty newline at the end so that value can be appended.

And now this code goes in respective `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
# --- Git revision ---
add_dependencies(your_awesome_target gitrev)      #put name of your target here
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})  #so that the include file is found
set(gitrev_in git-rev.h.in)                       #just filenames, feel free to change them...
set(gitrev git-rev.h)
add_custom_target(gitrev
  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove -f ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${gitrev}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${gitrev_in} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${gitrev}
  COMMAND git rev-parse HEAD >> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${gitrev}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}         #very important, otherwise git repo might not be found in shadow build
  VERBATIM                                              #portability wanted
)
```

This command ensuers that the `git-rev.h.in` is copied in the build tree as `git-rev.h` and git revision is appended at its end.

So all you need to do next is include `git-rev.h` in one of your files and do whatever you want with the `GIT_REV` macro, which yields current git revision hash as a string value.

The nice thing about this solution is that the `git-rev.h` is recreated each time you build the associated target, so you don't have to run `cmake` over and over again.

It also should be pretty portable - no non-portable external tools were used and even the bloody stupid windows cmd supports the `>` and `>>` operators ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I can't help you with the CMake side, but with respect to **Git side** I would recommend taking a look how Linux kernel and Git project itself does it, via [GIT-VERSION-GEN](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=GIT-VERSION-GEN;hb=master) script, or how tig does it in its [Makefile](http://repo.or.cz/w/tig.git?a=blob;f=Makefile), by using **`git describe`** if there is git repository present, falling back to "`version`" / "`VERSION`" / "`GIT-VERSION-FILE`" generated and present in tarballs, finally falling back to default value hardcoded in script (or Makefile).

The first part (using `git describe`) requires that you tag releases using annotated (and possibly GPG signed) tags.  Or use `git describe --tags` to use also lightweight tags.

Answer (score 1):

If CMake doesn't have a built-in capability to do this substitution, then you could write a wrapper shell script that reads a template file, substitutes the SHA1 hash as above in the correct location (using `sed`, for example), creates the real CMake build file, and then calls CMake to build your project.

A slightly different approach might be to make the SHA1 substitution *optional*. You would create the CMake file with a dummy hash value such as `"NO_OFFICIAL_SHA1_HASH"`. When developers build their own builds from their working directories, the built code would not include a SHA1 hash value (only the dummy value) because the code from the working directory doesn't even have a corresponding SHA1 hash value yet.

On the other hand, when an official build is made by your build server, from sources pulled from a central repository, then you know the SHA1 hash value for the source code. At that point, you can substitute the hash value in the CMake file and then run CMake.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty, possibly not portable way to get the git SHA-1 into a C or C++ project using CMake, I use this in CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_target(git_revision.h
 git log -1 "--format=format:#define GIT_REVISION \"%H\"%n" HEAD > git_revision.h
 WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} VERBATIM)
```

It assumes that `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is part of a git repository, and that git is available on the system, and that an output redirection will be properly parsed by the shell.

You can then make this target a dependency of any other target using

```
add_dependencies(your_program git_revision.h)
```

Each time `your_program` is built, the Makefile (or other build system, if this works on other build systems) will recreate git_revision.h in the source directory, with the contents

```
#define GIT_REVISION "<SHA-1 of the current git revision>"
```

So you can `#include git_revision.h` from some source code file and use it that way. Note that the header is created at literally *every* build, i.e. even if every other object file is up to date, it will still run this command to recreate git_revision.h. I figure that shouldn't be a huge problem because usually you don't rebuild the same git revision over and over again, but it's something to be aware of, and if it *is* a problem for you, then don't use this. (It's probably possible to hack up a workaround using `add_custom_command` but I haven't needed it so far.)