# output from custom script as define macro

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have C++ project using cmake. I'd like to have versioning (in meaning of provide unique `./myapp --version` output) based on git commits. Manually it's something like

```
gcc ... -DVERSION=$(git rev-list|wc -l)
```

and using VERSION macro if defined in code.

This works as expected. But how should I write it into `CMakeLists.txt` (let's use echo for simplicity)? How should I escape it?

```
add_definitions(-DVERSION="$(echo 1)")
```

Comment: Similar, but not identical to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435953/how-can-i-pass-git-sha1-to-compiler-as-definition-using-cmake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cmake 2.8.8 you can:

```
add_definitions(demo -D`echo VERSION=\\`git rev-list HEAD|wc -l\\``)
```

and:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("Version: %d", VERSION);
```

To compile as:

```
/usr/bin/gcc   -std=c99 demo -D`echo VERSION=\`git rev-list HEAD|wc -l\`` -o CMakeFiles/demo.dir/src/demo.c.o   -c /home/doug/projects/libar/src/demo.c
```

And results in:

```
build$ ./demo
Version: 88
```

This seems to be what you actually want.