# How to force re-run of cmake, or add functions to makefile through CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, git, cmake

I'd like to keep very close track of what version of my code I'm using for documentation purposes. Therefore I'd like to display the version of code I have compiled every time I run my program..

I've been using this previous question as reference.

[How can I pass git SHA1 to compiler as definition using cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435953/how-can-i-pass-git-sha1-to-compiler-as-definition-using-cmake)

I am using the two files that Ryan Pavlik suggested from his github repo, seen below:
https://github.com/rpavlik/cmake-modules/blob/master/GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake.in#L13
https://github.com/rpavlik/cmake-modules/blob/master/GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake

And I have the following:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
include(GetGitRevisionDescription)
get_git_head_revision(GIT_REFSPEC GITHASH)

set(test_GITHASH "\"${GITHASH}\"")

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
configure_file ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/testgithash.h.in"
                "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/testgithash.h" )
```

**testgithash.h.in**

```
#define test_GITHASH @test_GITHASH@
```

So far I have my final executable displaying the hash from my *testgithash.h* file that is generated, but that header file is only refreshed when I run *cmake*. So really my question is, does anyone know of way that I can force *cmake* to re-run when I run *make* if my hash has changed? Or is there a way I can put the git hash functionality I'm looking for directly into my generated makefile rather than in my CMakeLists.txt?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I've been able to figure out, the only way to force CMake to be rerun on some external condition is to have it `include` a file whose timestamp has been modified. Something like this:

```
# Somewhere in your CMakeLists.txt
include(external.stamp)
```

Then CMake will be rerun when `external.stamp` is updated.

In your case, maybe you could have a post-commit hook in git touch an (empty) file when a commit is made, then include that in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: How can have `cmake` re-run when the timestamp of `CMakeCache.txt` changes ?