# CMAKE 3.8, imported targets not available for Boost version

Tags: boost, cmake, cmake-gui

I'm on Windows 10 and got this error when generating solution using CMake-GUI:

```
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:765 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:869 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1472 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
```

I know it's been asked and answered here [CMake finds Boost but the imported targets not available for Boost version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123509/cmake-finds-boost-but-the-imported-targets-not-available-for-boost-version)
but the solution in there (upgrading CMake) doesn't work for me, still get the same error after upgrading from 3.7 to 3.8

**Update**
My boost version is `106300`. 
Content of CMakeList file is below:

```
# doc/CMakeLists.txt uses configure_file behavior from CMake 2.8
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(tpie)

include_directories(.)
add_definitions(-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE)

#### CONFIG.H Checks:
include(CheckIncludeFiles)

if(NOT WIN32) 
    add_definitions("-Wall -Wextra")
endif(NOT WIN32)

if(WIN32)
    add_definitions("-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN /bigobj")
endif(WIN32)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH};${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules/")
#### Dependencies
## Boost
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.40.0" "1.40" "1.41" "1.41.0" "1.42" "1.42.0" "1.43" "1.43.0" "1.44" "1.44.0" "1.45" "1.45.0")
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
if(WIN32)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS    ON)
endif(WIN32)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS date_time filesystem system REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories( ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

if(TPIE_FRACTIONDB_DIR_INL) 
  include_directories(${TPIE_FRACTIONDB_DIR_INL})
endif(TPIE_FRACTIONDB_DIR_INL)

check_include_files("unistd.h" TPIE_HAVE_UNISTD_H)
check_include_files("sys/unistd.h" TPIE_HAVE_SYS_UNISTD_H)

# Ryan Pavlik's Git revision description helper
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/4318642
include(GetGitRevisionDescription)
get_git_head_revision(GIT_REFSPEC GIT_COMMIT)

## Snappy
option(TPIE_USE_SNAPPY "Use Snappy, a fast compressor/decompressor" ON)
if(TPIE_USE_SNAPPY)
    find_package(Snappy)
    if(${Snappy_FOUND})
        set(TPIE_HAS_SNAPPY ON)
        include_directories(${Snappy_INCLUDE_DIR})
    else(${Snappy_FOUND})
        set(TPIE_HAS_SNAPPY OFF)
    endif(${Snappy_FOUND})
endif(TPIE_USE_SNAPPY)

#### Installation paths
#Default paths
set(BIN_INSTALL_DIR bin)
set(LIB_INSTALL_DIR lib)
set(HEADERS_INSTALL_DIR include/tpie)
if (WIN32)
    set(DOC_INSTALL_DIR doc)
else(WIN32)
    set(DOC_INSTALL_DIR "share/doc/tpie")
endif(WIN32)

set(INSTALL_TARGETS_DEFAULT_ARGS
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${BIN_INSTALL_DIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}
)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE) 
  string(TOUPPER ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} bt)
  string(REGEX MATCH " -DNDEBUG " TPIE_NDEBUG " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${bt}} ")
else()
  option(TPIE_NDEBUG "Disable debugging information" ON)
endif()

set(TPIE_S ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(TPIE_B ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

if(NOT WIN32) 
       set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif()

configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tpie/config.h.cmake ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tpie/config.h)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tpie/config.h DESTINATION ${HEADERS_INSTALL_DIR})
add_subdirectory(tpie)

add_subdirectory(doc)

option(COMPILE_TEST "Compile test programs" ON)
option(TPL_LOGGING "Enable tpie logging." ON)
option(TPIE_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS "Enable warnings for deprecated classes, methods and typedefs" OFF)
option(TPIE_PARALLEL_SORT "Enable parallel quick sort implementation" ON)

if (COMPILE_TEST)
    ENABLE_TESTING()
    add_subdirectory(test)
    add_subdirectory(apps)
endif (COMPILE_TEST)

include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "rav@cs.au.dk")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR TGZ)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "TPIE")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "The TPIE maintainers")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.md")
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/COPYING.md")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "TPIE ${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}")
if(WIN32 AND NOT UNIX)
  # There is a bug in NSI that does not handle full unix paths properly. Make
  # sure there is at least one set of four (4) backlasshes.
  #set(CPACK_PACKAGE_ICON "${CMake_SOURCE_DIR}/Utilities/Release\\\\InstallIcon.bmp")
  set(CPACK_NSIS_DISPLAY_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY} ${CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY}")
  set(CPACK_NSIS_HELP_LINK "http:\\\\\\\\thomasmoelhave.github.com/tpie/")
  set(CPACK_NSIS_URL_INFO_ABOUT "http:\\\\\\\\thomasmoelhave.github.com/tpie/")
  set(CPACK_NSIS_CONTACT ${CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT})
  set(CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH ON)
  list(APPEND CPACK_GENERATOR NSIS)
else(WIN32 AND NOT UNIX)
  list(APPEND CPACK_GENERATOR DEB)
endif(WIN32 AND NOT UNIX)

install(DIRECTORY tpie
    DESTINATION include
    FILES_MATCHING REGEX "\\.h$|\\.inl$"
    PATTERN "deadcode" EXCLUDE)

install(DIRECTORY share/tpie
    DESTINATION share)

include(CPack)
```

Any other idea? tks

Comment: What is the content of your cmake file? Which version of boost is installed in your system?

Comment: @wasthishelpful updated my question

Comment: Try removing the line with `Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS`.

Comment: Have you delete your build directory and re-run CMake with the latest version?

Comment: use `-DBOOST_DEBUG=ON` to get more details

Comment: @zaufi `Manually-specified variables were not used by the project: BOOST_DEBUG`; is this a project-specific thing or is it supposed to be a generic CMake option?

Comment: Turns out the parameter name is case sensitive; should be `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake finds Boost but the imported targets not available for Boost version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123509/cmake-finds-boost-but-the-imported-targets-not-available-for-boost-version)

Answer (score 4):

Your CMAKE is too old for the boost 1.63.
Reinstall a newer CMAKE or do this(according to FindBoost.cmake source code in cmake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake line 516):

Note: to add a new Boost release, run

```
 % cmake -DBOOST_DIR=/path/to/boost/source -P Utilities/Scripts/BoostScanDeps.cmake
```

Or, Just modify that line from
`elseif(NOT Boost_VERSION VERSION_LESS 106200 AND Boost_VERSION VERSION_LESS 106300)`
to

```
elseif(NOT Boost_VERSION VERSION_LESS 106200 AND Boost_VERSION VERSION_LESS 106500)
```

Comment: I have Boost 1.65.1 and CMake 3.9.2 and I keep getting "Imported targets not available for Boost version 106501". I can't find any documentation on BoostScanDeps.cmake; does it update an index file or something? This SO answer is one of the few non-git search results I've found...

Comment: change that line to "... Boost_VERSION VERSION_LESS 106502". I think it is the same