# Read GitHub Pull Request information from CMake

Tags: github, cmake

In past embedded projects I was able to pass the git SHA-1 used to configure the build to a generated source file using CMake. This was very useful as I had a logging message with this git SHA-1 that can always tell me the exact version of the software running on my device.

Now I am looking for a way to put additional versioning information to that log like the GitHub pull request number or URL. Is that even possible to achieve via git & CMake? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to follow the **same approach** as with adding git SHA-1?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you at least include in your question post, the approach that you used to retrieve the SHA-1?

Comment: Have you seen the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1435953/3987854) question?